# Database Design Primay Key, ID vs String

Tags: database, database-design

I am currently planning to develop a music streaming application. And i am wondering what would be better as a primary key in my tables on the server. An ID int or a Unique String.

> Methods 1:

Songs Table:
**SongID**(int), Title(string), *Artist**(string), Length(int), *Album**(string)

Genre Table
**Genre**(string), Name(string)

SongGenre:
***SongID****(int), ***Genre****(string)

> Method 2

Songs Table:
**SongID**(int), Title(string), *ArtistID**(int), Length(int), *AlbumID**(int)

Genre Table
**GenreID**(int), Name(string)

SongGenre:
***SongID****(int), ***GenreID****(int)

Key: **Bold** = Primary Key, *Field** = Foreign Key

I'm currently designing using method 2 as I believe it will speed up lookup performance and use less space as an int takes a lot less space then a string.

Is there any reason this isn't a good idea? Is there anything I should be aware of?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are doing the right thing - identity field should be numeric and not string based, both for space saving and for performance reasons (matching keys on strings is slower than matching on integers).

Comment: -1: These are the wrong reasons to be making design decisions.  Make the design decisions based on whether or not it is the right _design_.  Then, if there are performance problems, tune and redesign as necessary.

Comment: I'm with Max on this.  Design with natural keys.  This is yet another instance of premature optimisation.  Technical keys have a place, but they're not free

Comment: -1: Integers do not make a good ID. Outside your system there can be several different ways an integer could be handled but there are fewer ways a string can be handled. This leaves your ID more robust when you're moving data across systems ('m sure you'll do that one day). Having integer for space and performance is pre-mature as Max pointed out. I believe numeric datatypes should be left for computation purposes.

Comment: @Oded I might agree with you on that. But I see it much often in my space and hence YMMV. It's definitely a trade off. I tend towards String because- is performance or storage going to be a bigger problem in future? Probably no- Moore's law. Is data inconsistency going to be an issue? Yes, because there are x systems today to handle data and tomorrow it's gonna be x + y. If you say your system is going to be in silo forever (I bet no), you're good with anything. Don't care.

Comment: "Because p3rf0rm4nce!" is such an easy criteria to consider, because it's just one criteria, and you can post an answer and sound smart. Reality is full of multiple criteria, and it's naturally harder to give a straight forward answer if you're trying to give a truer answer.  In this case, the performance is likely the same for integer or string since the unique ID will be sorted at the database level (then a string becomes a number anyway) so the database can do a binary search and very quickly find any ID. This is not the part of the problem that you should be concerning yourself with.

Answer (score 32):

> Is there any reason this isn't a good idea? Is there anything I should be aware of?

Yes. Integer IDs are very bad if you need to uniquely identify the same data outside of a single database. For example, if you have to copy the same data into another database system with potentially pre-existing data or you have a distributed database. The biggest thing to be aware of is that an integer like `7481` has no meaning outside of that one database. If later on you need to grow that database, it may be impossible without surgically removing your data.

The other thing to keep in mind is that integer IDs aren't as flexible so they can't easily be used for exceptional cases. The designers of the Internet Protocol understood this and took precautions by allocating certain blocks of numbers as "special" in one way or another (broadcast IPs, private IPs, network IPs). But that was only possible because there's a *protocol* surrounding the usage of those numbers. Many databases don't operate within such a well-defined protocol.

FWIW, it's kind of like trying to decide if having a "strongly typed" programming paradigm is better than a "weakly/dynamically typed" programming paradigm. It will depend on what you need to do.

Comment: IP addresses are a particularly apt example. They are no longer big enough for their intended purpose, yet they still linger because changing the system at this point is such a monumental task.

Answer (score 16):

From the software perspective the GUID is better as its unique globally.

Quotes from: [Primary Keys: IDs versus GUIDs](http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/)

> Using a GUID as a row identity value feels more natural-- and
>   certainly more truly unique-- than a 32-bit integer. Database guru Joe
>   Celko [seems to agree](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/msg/6d61dbf80d6f0fb6?hl=en&lr=&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&rnum=14). GUID primary keys are a natural fit for many
>   development scenarios, such as replication, or when you need to
>   generate primary keys outside the database. But it's still a question
>   of balancing the tradeoffs between traditional 4-byte integer IDs and
>   16-byte GUIDs:
>
> **GUID Pros**
>
> - Unique across every table, every database, every server
> - Allows easy merging of records from different databases
> - Allows easy distribution of databases across multiple servers
> - You can generate IDs anywhere, instead of having to roundtrip to the database
> - Most replication scenarios require GUID columns anyway
>
> **GUID Cons**
>
> - It is a whopping 4 times larger than the traditional 4-byte index value; this can have serious performance and storage implications if
>     you're not careful
> - Cumbersome to debug where userid='{BAE7DF4-DDF-3RG-5TY3E3RF456AS10}'
> - The generated GUIDs should be partially sequential for best performance (eg, newsequentialid() on SQL 2005) and to enable use of
>     clustered indexes

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, @michaelbn!  For most databases, integer-based unique ID are clearly appropriate, and I've used them in countless applications for decades.  However, there are other applications where text-based ID are better. For my current application, integer-based unique IDs have been proving problematic to the database design - so I went hunting for information on text-based unique IDs.  Your answer was absolutely perfect for my needs: I now know exactly the direction to take.  Thank you!

Comment: "The generated GUIDs should be partially sequential for best performance". Could someone expand on this? This sequentiality of GUIDs commits  to the best performance?

Comment: @origaminal , index updates is one of the problems. If you add record totally random then the index might need extra work to insert the reference to the correct place.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is: use ids.

You'll be able to rename that "Genre" with 20000 songs without breaking anything.

The idea behind this is that the id identifies the row in the table. Whatever the row has is something that doesn't matters in this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is in large part a matter of personal preference.

My personal opinion and practice is to always use integer keys and to always use surrogate rather than natural keys (so never use anything like social security number or the genre name directly).

There are cases where an auto number field is not appropriate or does not scale. In these cases it can make sense to use a GUID, which can be a string in databases that do not have a native datatype for it.