# Any reason to have a numerical ID in a database?

Tags: database, linux, postgresql, solr

I basically have a lot of different databases which get combined into one SOLR store. It has to be this way, and I cannot change it.

I was giving each item in each database a unique ID but when I combined the databases into SOLR I found that I was having more than one item with the same ID, for example:

```
Database A
Itemid: 1

Database B
Itemid: 1

SOLR:
Itemid: 1
Itemid: 1
```

Instead I am now having my main ID with the database name before it, like this:

```
Database A
Itemid: A1

Database B
Itemid: B1

SOLR:
Itemid: A1
Itemid: B1
```

My question is, is there any valid reason for having a non numerical ID, can I still do sorting based on these IDs?

Comment: Show more code! What are the database schemas of the original bases? How did you merge them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care about performance than it's better to stick with numeric IDs. (See [Database Design Primay Key, ID vs String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551776/database-design-primay-key-id-vs-string))

But to accomplish your task I would add the database name prefixes to Solr IDs at the data importing stage. So you would have:

```
Database A
Itemid: 1

Database B
Itemid: 1

SOLR:
Itemid: A1
Itemid: B1
```

Comment: How can I designate the prefix in each database though so I can cross reference them? For example if I want to make a connection from my Database to Solr, how can I relate the letter (A) to the specific database?

Comment: Bascially I just want to somehow put the label on the database, to say that this is database "A" so when cross referencing on solr, it should be "A<ID>"

Comment: It depends on your architecture. If your have a service layer that "knows" about all the databases and is responsible for all the cross database and Solr communications than it would be enough to maintain some enum or a map somewhere in your code to assign the labels to the databases. Or if you want (or can) you may add a small table into all your databases to store the metadata (e.g. MY_INFO_TABLE) and store the label there.